# what is the associate between install, deploy and release?

Tags: installation, release, deployment

what is the associate between install, deploy and release ? i am often refused with these conceptions, who can give me a detail, thanks!

BTW: i think "release" includes "install" and "deploy", right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A software "release" means it is released to the public for use. Normally after testing and beta phases are over.

A "deploy" is when software is physically put in production (or test system).

An "install" implies an automated way to deploy.